# GORM: Is it possible to load a domain object with errors?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Recently we've had a new requirement to check our domain objects for errors after we load them from the database a la:

```
DomainType domain = DomainType.get(longDomainTypeId)
```

We must now add an error check on the loaded domain:

```
if(domain.hasErrors()) {
    //report any errors and return failed
}
```

If the database constraints are the same as the domain constraints (not null, VARCHAR length, etc) how could it be possible to have a load error? Is this a check to validate the database connection is still valid?

I'm really just curious to know what we could possibly expect to go wrong here that would not be a catastrophic app/db connection failure...

Comment: I know I've had trouble loading objects that are missing fields that changed to be required (without changing the db).  I don't think an object will load if there are constraint violations.  You may just try loading all the objects, and see which ones fail :)

Comment: Anything that isn't reflected as database constraints (e.g. custom `validator`) could cause validation errors on an instance that had been persisted prior to the addition of the custom `validator`. That's just one example.

Comment: In that case though, you would not want to fail an edit operation, you'd want to update the attributes that fail the current constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of GORM constraints

1. Those that are enforced at the database layer, e.g. nullability, max length
2. Those that are enforced programatically, e.g. those implemented by custom validators

Assuming your DB schema is in synch with with your GORM constraints it's possible for data to be in your database that would be rejected by (2) if:

- Data is written to the database which is isn't validated by GORM
- Constraints of type (2) were added without performing a correct data migration beforehand

Comment: Indeed. So why would one fail an edit operation on the load of that object from the database? Makes no sense to me,